# Division Assembly in MSP430

Tags: msp430, assembly

I have been trying to implement an assembly routine in MSP430 for division. I already got the code for the division from the Horner Division Algorithm. The problem is that I only got the integer part. How I can get the fractional part from a division? For example: 5/2 = 2.5. How do I get the 0.5 part?

Comment: The MSP430 does not have a floating-point data type. How would the fractional part be represented?

Answer (score 1):

You should get the remainder.

To turn that into a fraction you first need to decide between fixed and floating point; and if fixed, how many fractional bits.

Fixed point is easy : if you decide you want 8 fractional bits, just divide 2^8 * remainder / denominator, and use the size of that operation's remainder to determine rounding.

In your example, that would give

(256 * 1) / 2 = 128 as your fractional part, i.e. 128 / 256 = 0.5

Or for 3 fractional (decimal) digits, just compute 10^3 * remainder / denominator.

For floating point you would use a floating point library; it's far too complex to seriously consider rolling your own.

Comment: The result should be with 3 digits for the fractional part and least significant bit of that part should be rounded. So yes it is a fixed point format.

Comment: correction: fraction = (2^8 * remainder)/denominator

Comment: How that's going to be represented in a register in the MSP430?

Comment: That's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
 q  =(num * 2^n)/ denom
```

as an integer division; the result will have `n` extra, fractional, bits. So with n=8,

```
(5*256)/2 = 640
```

which is 2.5 * 256  or 2 * 256 + (128/256).